# Installing and using React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, netbeans, npm

I have spent a long time simply trying to install React and React-DOM.

I start my script with:

```
var React = require('react'); 
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

I used Node and NPM to install into my project directory, and I can see they've been successfully installed in my NetBeans IDE. I open `Project Setting->Javascript Libraries->NPM` and I can see `React v15.4.2` and `React-DOM v15.4.2`.

Despite this I still get the error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require 
   (21:07:49:681 | error, javascript)
   at global code (public_html/main.js:8:20)
```

If anyone has a suggestion then I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using something like Wepback to package it for the web?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/bower_and_node_js_in

Comment: Thank you for the link! This looks very helpful. And I haven't set up webpack with react yet, I plan to do so now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work. Include your `react.js` and `react-dom.js` libraries from npm packages to the main page of your project (i.e. index.html). Also remember to add `babel.js` - it's not connected with your issue, just mentioning for the future.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I guess I jumped the gun in thinking React would be auto compiled. I'll look into setting it up with Webpack. Do I still need to use Babel if I use Webpack?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Look here for the details https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `require()` in the browser just yet (and the spec will be different from the RequireJS syntax anyway) . If you want to get started with React, I recommend you try [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)  to begin with. As soon as you feel comfortable with the workflow, you can try to set up your own development and production environment, using Gulp, Browserify or the more popular Webpack module.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at what else needs to be done to compile React.